# Automatically Add a Period After Last Page Number in Each Index Entry

Tags: indexing, imakeidx, makeindex, customize

Consider the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\newcommand\pagedot[1]{#1.}
\usepackage{idxlayout}

\begin{document}
This is a sentence.\index{\textbf{Corresponds to the first sentence}|pagedot}

This is another sentence.\index{\textbf{Corresponds to the second sentence}}

This is another sentence.\index{\textbf{Corresponds to the third sentence}}
\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

which produces the Index:

[image]

As you can see, I have added a period after the page number in the first entry by invoking the newly defined command, `pagedot`. However, I would like to do similarly for every index entry which I may have.

QUESTION: How may I automatically add a period after the last page number of each index entry?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the question have already been answered in the other post by comments. I made a working example of using the style file (`*.ist`) to set the `delim_t` key to `"."` in order to generate a period after each entry after the very last page number.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{style.ist}
delim_t "."
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[options=-s style.ist]
\usepackage{idxlayout}
\idxlayout{columns=1}
\begin{document}
This is a sentence.\index{\textbf{Corresponds to the first sentence}}

This is another sentence.\index{\textbf{Corresponds to the second sentence}}

This is another sentence.\index{\textbf{Corresponds to the third sentence}}

\clearpage
This is a sentence.\index{\textbf{Corresponds to the first sentence}}

This is another sentence.\index{\textbf{Corresponds to the second sentence}}

\clearpage
This is a sentence.\index{\textbf{Corresponds to the first sentence}}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you kindly for this answer.

Comment: @DDS You're welcome.