# Idxlayout Paragraph Form---Adding a Period to Certain Page Numbers

Tags: indexing, delimiters, imakeidx, makeindex, idxlayout

This is a follow-up to [Automatically Add a Period After Last Page Number in Each Index Entry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/707314/automatically-add-a-period-after-last-page-number-in-each-index-entry)

Consider the MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{style.ist}
delim_t "." 
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
%\makeindex
\makeindex[options=-s style.ist]
\newcommand\pagedot[1]{#1.} % Adds a period to a particular entry.
\usepackage[itemlayout=singlepar]{idxlayout}

\begin{document}
This is a sentence.\index{Index entry}

This is another sentence.\index{Yet another index entry}

\newpage
This is another sentence.\index{Yet another index entry!subentry}
\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

This produces the Index output:

[image]

Since the Index entries are displayed in paragraph form, I would like for only the last page number of each entry to have a period following the page number. (So, in this case, for instance, "Yet another index entry, 1.;" would be display instead as "Yet another index entry, 1;")

How may the above code be modified in order to accomplish this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a new command `\checknextchar` to test if page number followed by `subitem` or `subsubitem`, if not add a period. Then use `\\checknextchar` as the key value for `delim_t`

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{style.ist}
delim_t "\\checknextchar" 
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\newcommand{\checknextchar}[1]{%
\ifx\subitem#1\subitem\else\ifx\subsubitem#1\subsubitem\else.\fi\fi%
}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[options=-s style.ist]
\newcommand\pagedot[1]{#1.} % Adds a period to a particular entry.
\usepackage[itemlayout=singlepar]{idxlayout}

\begin{document}
This is a sentence.\index{Index entry}

This is another sentence.\index{Yet another index entry}

This is another sentence.\index{this is another index entry}

\newpage
This is another sentence.\index{this is another index entry!subentry}

This is another sentence.\index{Yet another index entry!subentry}

\newpage
This is another sentence.\index{Yet another index entry!subentry!subsubentry}

\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your output is exactly what I want; however, I cannot seem to reproduce it. I am compiling with `pdflatex`.  Should I be running your code any other way than the way I compiled my MWE? Thanks.

Comment: @DDS Did you overwrite the `style.ist` file? If there is already a `style.ist` in the working directory, you need put [overwrite] option to `filecontents` env. (e.g. `\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{style.ist}`). Or, get rid of `filecontents` env, edit the `style.ist` file directly.

Comment: That seems to have been the problem. Many thanks!!

Comment: Also ,I don't know if it matters or not---but when I had trouble locating the `ist` file, I tried changing `.ist` to `.mst` in the two instances where it occurs in your code---and it worked fine. (I'm not sure what the difference is between ist and mst). Thank you for having posted your answer. It is very helpful.

Comment: @DDS I think `ist` is the standard extension name for index style file. If you try `\makeindex[options=-s style]`, the program will try to look the file `style.ist` in the directory not `style.mst`. If you have `style.mst` in your directory, the program won't use that. But you can always set extension name explicitly like `\makeindex[options=-s style.mst]` .

Comment: And many thanks for this information.

Comment: Such a nice suggestion

Comment: Sorry to ask, can you help me on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/712432/index-subentries-be-alphabetized-by-the-topics-following-the-connective-words-ph please.