# Index subentries be alphabetized by the topics following the connective words/phrase

Tags: indexing, order

I need to arrange the subentries in alpha order not with the words like `and`, `as`, `the`, and `for` etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\makeindex
\begin{document}


This is for test\index{boundary layer}\index{boundary layer!and Toner-Tu theory of pipe ow}
\index{boundary layer!defined}
\index{boundary layer!Prandtl treatment of}
\index{boundary layer!thickness}
\index{boundary layer!Toner-Tu theory compared to Newtonian fluid}

\clearpage

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Output came as:

[image]

But, per my requirement the desired output should be as:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the prefix to be ignored at the end, so that it's essentially not considered for sorting. Then you need to massage the entry:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex

\NewDocumentCommand{\prf}{m}{#1}

\NewCommandCopy{\originalsubitem}{\subitem}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\RenewDocumentCommand{\subitem}{}
 {
  \originalsubitem
  \peek_regex_replace_once:nn { ([^,]*) \c{prf}+ ([^,]*) \, } { \2\ \1, }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

This is for test\index{boundary layer}\index{boundary layer!Toner-Tu theory of pipe ow\prf{and}}
\index{boundary layer!defined}
\index{boundary layer!Prandtl treatment of}
\index{boundary layer!thickness}
\index{boundary layer!Toner-Tu theory compared to Newtonian fluid}

\index{c}
\index{d}
\index{e}
\index{f}
\index{g}
\index{h}
\index{i}
\index{j}
\index{k}

\clearpage

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Here I used `imakeidx` in order to make running the test easier.

The idea is to ask `\subitem` to issue the original command and then look for a `\prf` token. If it's present, then whatever goes from it to the comma that delimits the entry is put at the beginning followed by a space.

[image]

Comment: Really such a nice suggestion. Is this possible to achieve this using like some `.ist` file, without the `\index` tag modification? If no way, then, I'll go with this, please advise.

Comment: Because I'm having huge number of Index entries in my document, changing the tags caused huge time, that's why I asked, thanks

Comment: @GowriSaro This would require massive surgery on the `\index` command.

Comment: Much thanks, will follow as you suggested